# Getting Network Error and empty dropdown on React-Select Async

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-select

I am trying to implement react-select on my React application. My API endpoint works with a simple get request, and I am sure it sends response such as:

```
[
  {
    value: 123,
    label: "Michael Carrick",
    first_name: "Michael",
    last_name: "Carrick",
    country: "England",
    first_nationality: "England",
    team_id: 134,
    Team.name: "Manchester United"
  },
  {
    value: 234,
    label: "Jack Clarke",
    first_name: "Jack",
    last_name: "Clarke",
    country: "England",
    first_nationality: null,
    team_id: 254,
    Team.name: "Leeds United"
  }
]
```

In my component, I have the following part:

```
const promiseOptions = (inputValue) => {
  axios.get('URL?q=' + inputValue)
    .then(res => {
      const data = res.data;
      return data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

export default class extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: null,
      inputValue: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('URL')
    .then(res => {
      const data = res.data;
      this.setState({ data });
      return data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
  }

  handleInputChange (newValue) => {
    this.setState({ inputValue });
    return inputValue;
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <AsyncSelect cacheOptions defaultOptions loadOptions={promiseOptions} />
    )
  }
}
```

When I load the page, I click the dropdown select box but it says 'No options'. When I type something to the box, I can see what I type but on console, I get errors everytime input changes:

```
VM6467:1 GET ENDPOINT-URL?q=c 0 ()
(anonymous) @ VM6467:1
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:178
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:59
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:51
Axios.(anonymous function) @ Axios.js:61
wrap @ bind.js:9
promiseOptions @ select.js:14
loadOptions @ Async.js:167
(anonymous) @ Async.js:88
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:10764
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:10797
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:14264
commitAllLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:15342
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:100
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:138
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:187
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:15481
completeRoot @ react-dom.development.js:16496
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:16440
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:16358
flushInteractiveUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:16605
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2143
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4551
interactiveUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:16592
interactiveUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2150
dispatchInteractiveEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4528
select.js:20 Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

I tried to follow the sample example as much as possible but cannot make it work, as it seems.

Edit: CORS is allowed on my Express app.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code, you need to use a callback:

`const promiseOptions = (inputValue, callback) => { //add callback param
  axios.get('URL?q=' + inputValue)
    .then(res => {
      const data = res.data;
      callback(data); //<= using callback
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}`

Comment: When using callback, I get `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` error.

Comment: where do you see that error? in the console? do you have an ad blocker?

Comment: Yes, but does not matter even if I turn it off.

Comment: but that is a network error, not react, not JS... you need to turn it off not for the current page, but for "URL" domain

Comment: try in another browser, maybe is another plugin/addon you are using... but the way of using the promise, is with the callback